# How to use Grand total for multiple column in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have one table with three columns  say c1,c2 and c3. I want to show grant total for all three columns. I have tried but grand total's logic was working only with column and not for three column.
So is there any way to do so..

Answer (score 1):

If all three columns are measures then you should be able to just go to Analysis->Totals->Show Column Grand Totals.

Or are you also trying to count a dimension? Your question is not very clear.